# Function only work once

Tags: jquery

Why do my code only work once on same element?

Here is my buttons:

```
<button class="btn-warning line-focus" id="1">Focus</button>
<button class="btn-default line-normal" id="2">Normal</button>
<button class="btn-warning line-focus" id="3">Focus</button>
<button class="btn-warning line-focus" id="4">Focus</button>
<button class="btn-warning line-focus" id="5">Focus</button>
```

here is my jQuery script:

```
$(".line-focus").live('click', function() {
    //unfocus line
    var lineid = this.id;
        $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
        $(this).removeClass("line-focus");
        $(this).addClass("line-normal");
        $(this).addClass("btn-default");
        $(this).text('Normal');
});


$(".line-normal").live('click', function() {
    //focus line
    var lineid = this.id;
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default");
        $(this).removeClass("line-normal");
        $(this).addClass("line-focus");
        $(this).addClass("btn-warning");
        $(this).text('Focus');
});
```

What do i wrong? Should be possible to focus/unfocus the same button a million times

Comment: `live` is deprecated in new jQuery versions.

Comment: Use `on()` instead of `live()`.

Comment: I have tried to use `on()` but is the same. I use jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: That something is deprecated does not mean it does not work.

Comment: You bind the listeners to elements you modify afterwards. That won't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1ycx01f4/2/

Comment: `.live()` was removed in 1.9 so in this case it does mean it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are removing the clicked element class you'll be able to click again and you wouldn't get what you're expecting.

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/event-delegation) method:

```
$(document).on('click',".line-focus", function() {
    //unfocus line
    var lineid = this.id;
        $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
        $(this).removeClass("line-focus");
        $(this).addClass("line-normal");
        $(this).addClass("btn-default");
        $(this).text('Normal');
});


$(document).on('click',".line-normal", function() {
    //focus line
    var lineid = this.id;
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default");
        $(this).removeClass("line-normal");
        $(this).addClass("line-focus");
        $(this).addClass("btn-warning");
        $(this).text('Focus');
});
```

Also, I would like to recommend you to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live() method since you're using 1.10 version of jQuery.